# how to start iPython in xshell

Tags: ipython, xshell

I just begin to use xshell in Windows 7, it looks good, but **how can I enter interactive console of iPython in xshell?**

In cmd of windows, when I type "ipython", it will bring me to the interactive console automatically.

However, in xshell, I've tried several command like "ipython", "ipython console", all of them would not bring me to the interactive console of ipython.

BTW, I'm using xshell 5 (home/school edition) in Windows 7.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XShell, but searching for it, it looks like it talks to a remote computer over SSH or Telnet. If that's the case, then IPython will need to be installed on the computer you connect to.

Comment: @ThomasK, Thank you. I'm ssh to localhost, and yes, I've installed iPython already.

Comment: What do you see when you run `ipython`?

Comment: @ThomasK, nothing, just a blank, like the command is out of response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the response from technical support team of XSHELL, it seems xshell does not support interactive shell currently.

> 1. how can I enter interactive console of iPython in xshell? In cmd of windows, when I type "ipython", it will bring me to the interactive
>      console automatically. However, in xshell, I've tried several command
>      like "ipython", "ipython console", all of them would not bring me to
>      the interactive console of ipython.
>
> > > Xshell does not support interactive shell at this time. We are working on it.